# Mysql - Joining one to many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I wrote the following code in order to join one to many to many in Sql Server 2008 R2. This code partitions the select statement by an ID and orders so that I can grab the top three diagnosis:

```
   Left join (select zzAbstractlink, 
                DiagnosisCIHIValue,
                DiagnosisType,
                RowNumber = Row_Number() Over(Partition by zzAbstractlink order by DiagnosisOccurrence)
                from I10_Diagnosis_VR
                where DiagnosisType <> 'M') Dx1 on AB.AbstractID = Dx1.zzAbstractLink and Dx1.RowNumber = 1   
    Left join (select zzAbstractlink, 
                DiagnosisCIHIValue,
                DiagnosisType,
                RowNumber = Row_Number() Over(Partition by zzAbstractlink order by DiagnosisOccurrence)
                from I10_Diagnosis_VR
                where DiagnosisType <> 'M') Dx2 on AB.AbstractID = Dx2.zzAbstractLink and Dx2.RowNumber = 2
    left join (select zzAbstractlink, 
                DiagnosisCIHIValue,
                DiagnosisType,
                RowNumber = Row_Number() Over(Partition by zzAbstractlink order by DiagnosisOccurrence)
                from I10_Diagnosis_VR
                where DiagnosisType <> 'M') Dx3 on AB.AbstractID = Dx3.zzAbstractLink and Dx3.RowNumber = 3
```

I need to write same code in MySql. Anyone know how to achieve this?

here is some sample code:

```
create table person as 
(person varchar(10))

create table diagnosis as
( person varchar(10),
occurence varchar(10),
diagnosis varchar(10))


insert into person
values (1),(2)

insert into diagnosis
values (1,2,A),(1,1,B),(1,3,C),(1,4,D),(2,2,A),(2,3,B),(2,1,C)
```

select statment outcome:

```
Person  |DiagnosisOccurence1    |DiagnosisOccurence2
_____________________________________________________
1       |B                      |A
2       |C                      |A
```

Comment: I can't do the translation. But if you show proper CREATE and INSERT statements, I *might* be able to provide a solution.

Comment: Quite painfully.  MySQL does not support window functions.  I wouldn't recommend it as a replacement for SQL Server, if the database needs to support this type of query.

Comment: we aren't replacing the db. I work with both, wrote the above query for SQL Server 2008 but need to write something similar for a report in mysql

Comment: Then you need to provide sample data and expected output based on the sample data to be able to help you. But as @GordonLinoff has already pointed out: this is not going to be easy.